# How to assert that a void function will throw a exception?

Tags: java, assert

Our test code uses assert.

So is there any functions in assert class that can expect that a void function throws an exception?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Are you using JUnit, TestNG, or some other variant thereof?

Comment: The `assert` keyword in the language? Or method for assertion in some unit testing tool?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has no clarified a basic point that is key to answering the question, in spite of multiple requests to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test(expected=MyCustomException.class)
public void testBlahBlah_BlahBlah(){
     voidMethodThatThrowsException();
}
```

This annotation of JUnit is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that the OP is using JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I accomplish this:

First way is if I want to make sure an exception is thrown but not fail the test for it and I want to continue asserting.

```
try {
    myObject.methodThatShouldThrowAnException("baddata");
    assert.fail("Exception should have been thrown");
catch (SomeException e) { }

assert.equals(anotherMethod(), "hello");
```

The second way is if I don't want to do additional asserts (This is JUnit, could vary for the test framework you are using...TestNG has similar syntax):

```
@Test(expected = SomeException.class)
public void myTest() {
    myObject.methodThatShouldThrowAnException("baddata");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first way is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you found it solved your problem to help other people in the future...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most testing frameworks (notably JUnit) will allow you to specify an exception class, so that the test will fail if an exception is not thrown.

If you can't use this method, then you can just wrap it in a try/catch and do the assertion in the catch block.

Ex (using JUnit):

```
@Test(expected=SomeException.class)
public void testSomeFunction_expectedSomeException(){
    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
    clazz.someMethodThatThrowsTheException();
    fail("shouldn't have gotten here...");
}
```

Or:

```
//@Test -- this annotation may or may not be supported by your framework
public void testSomeFunction_expectedSomeException(){
    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
    try {
        clazz.someMethodThatThrowsTheException();
        fail("shouldn't have gotten here...");
    }
    catch (SomeException ex) {
        // assert...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        fail("Some other exception occurred, also not good");
    }
}
```